# How to make a lifetime constraint "pass through" from object to its grandchild?

Tags: rust, constraints, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm doing some experiments with lifetimes and the borrow checker. Imagine this first struct:

```rust
struct First {}

impl First {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }

    fn second(&self) -> Second {
        Second::new(self)
    }

    fn hello(&self) {
        println!("Hello");
    }
}
```

And the second, which has a lifetime constraint that depends on `First`:

```rust
struct Second<'a> {
    owner: &'a First,
}

impl<'a> Second<'a> {
    fn new(owner: &'a First) -> Self {
        Self { owner }
    }

    fn hello(&self) {
        self.owner.hello();
    }
}
```

The code above works perfectly fine: `Second` is created by `First`, and it cannot outlive `First`.

### The problem

Now let's modify `Second` so it can create a third struct, `Third`:

```rust
struct Second<'a> {
    owner: &'a First,
}

impl<'a> Second<'a> {
    fn new(owner: &'a First) -> Self {
        Self { owner }
    }

    fn third(&self) -> Third {
        Third::new(self.owner)
    }

    fn hello(&self) {
        self.owner.hello();
    }
}
```

And `Third` itself, which also depends on `First`:

```rust
struct Third<'a> {
    owner: &'a First,
}

impl<'a> Third<'a> {
    fn new(owner: &'a First) -> Self {
        Self { owner }
    }

    fn hello(&self) {
        self.owner.hello();
    }
}
```

I would imagine that, when creating an instance of `Third`, it would depend on `First`, but that's not the case. Actually `Third` depends on `Second`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let f = First::new();
    let t = {
        let sss = f.second();
        sss.third() // error: sss does not live long enough
    };
}
```

So, how can I make the lifetime constraint "pass through" from `First` to `Third`?

[Full playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=46ed81daed66206db91c38180c2609a8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust has rules how it infers lifetimes for functions: the [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html).

And those rules state that:

> - Each elided lifetime (*i.e. a type that should had have a lifetime, but doesn't, like `&T` that is actually `&'a T`*) in the parameters becomes a distinct lifetime parameter.
> - If there is exactly one lifetime used in the parameters (elided or not), that lifetime is assigned to *all* elided output lifetimes.
>
> In method signatures there is another rule
>
> - If the receiver has type `&Self` or `&mut Self`, then the lifetime of that reference to `Self` is assigned to all elided output lifetime parameters.

Let's take `First::second()` as an example. Its signature is:

```rust
fn second(&self) -> Second
```

Or, with all lifetimes explicitly elided (by the way, it is considered a good practice to explictly elide all lifetimes that are not on references, like `Second<'_>` in this example):

```
fn second(&'_ self) -> Second<'_>
```

So according to rule #1 we assign a new lifetime, let's call it `'a`, to `&self`:

```rust
fn second<'a>(&'a self) -> Second<'_>
```

Now, according to rule #3, we pick `'a` for `Second<'_>`:

```rust
fn second<'a>(&'a self) -> Second<'a>
```

That is, we return `Second` that has the same lifetime as the reference to `self`.

Now let's apply it to `Second::third()`...

```rust
fn third(&self) -> Third
// Becomes
fn third<'b>(&'b self) -> Third<'b> // Lifetime `'a` is already used
```

But this is **not** what we want! We want the resulting `Third` to depend on the lifetime of our contained `First` instance, not on the lifetime of `&self`! So what we really need is to use `Third<'a>`:

```rust
fn third(&self) -> Third<'a> { ... }
```

Now [it works beautifully](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=25dd6b52ad59a2a8c4648f5b751ac06e).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify the same lifetime of the inner reference in `Second` when creating `Third`:

```rust
impl<'a> Second<'a> {
    fn new(owner: &'a First) -> Self {
        Self { owner }
    }
    fn third(&self) -> Third<'a> {
        Third::new(self.owner)
    }
    fn hello(&self) {
        self.owner.hello();
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0e75b2eed9e540abbdae94bd373de20e)

It is the same as when creating `Second` from first:

```rust
impl First {
...
    fn second(&self) -> Second {
        Second::new(self)
    }
...
}
```

Here, second is bound to a `'self` lifetime, that is, it can live as much as that `&self` `First` instance. But in this case the compiler specify it for you.